# CSS transparent background fallback when images are disabled

Tags: javascript, css, image, background, transparency

I have a DIV with a transparent PNG background applied to it. Is there a way (use of JS is fine) for me to:

1. Have the transparency effect when images are enabled
2. Apply a normal solid background color to it when images are disabled

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I remember, if you set background-color and background-image, that would not work with transparent PNGs (over the transparency you will see background-color). 
Te solution is to use a special css class:

```
.trans_back { background:red }
DIV#trans_png { background:url(reddot.png); position:absolute; left:-9px; }
```

Then make a script:

```
$().ready(function(){
  $('#trans_png').load(function(){
    $('.tans_back').css('background',$(this).css('background'));
  });
});
```

DIV#trans_png is used to check if image is loaded, you can do it in way you like, I prefer simplest without scripting.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to supply both a css background-image and background-color. If images are disabled the color should still show up.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution that comes to my mind is that you could set up a solid background by default, then load the image(s) with JavaScript and apply transparency. If someone will have JS disabled or image download will fail then you will have the default solid background.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a

[jQuery lightbox](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/)

like thing.

Answer (score 0):

This is based on Thinker's post, but I found it didn't work.

I found that `$('#trans_png').load` didn't trigger (jquery 1.9.1, firefox) - I had to use the load event of an image's src, ie, `$('#logo img').attr('src', 'images/layout/logo.png').load(function() {`. Any image will do.

I also found that just copying the background didn't work, I had to explicitly clear the color and add the image url.

I also had to apply this change to several elements (sub-menu `ul`s), so added a loop within the load function:

```
$('#logo img').attr('src', 'images/layout/logo.png').load(function() {
    $("ul.MenuBarHorizontal ul").each(function() {
        $(this).css('background-color','none').css('background','none').css('background', $('#menu-trns-bg').css('background-image'));
    });
});
```

This is essentially Thinker's answer, fixed, however I couldn't fit this intelligibly into a comment.

Just to clarify, the ULs by default have `background-color: white;`, and the div is positioned off screen `div#menu-trns-bg {position: absolute;left:-3000px;background-image:url(../images/layout/body-bg.png);}` I'm using this on a Spry menu.

Comment: This seems to introduce a vulnerability on weak connections. I have occasionally seen the logo image fail to load if the CSS replacement Javascript doesn't complete. I've tried preloading the background image and returning true from the javascript routine but something breaks. Personally this isn't worth the risk so I have removed this code from my site.