# fallback for button text color if background-image is not loaded?

Tags: javascript, button, background-image, fallback

i have a button with a dark background-image png file with transparencies. the button text is white. if the background-image does not show i need a fallback to change the button text color to  black. how can this be done with javascript?
i found [CSS transparent background fallback when images are disabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315320/css-transparent-background-fallback-when-images-are-disabled/1315355#1315355) but this does not seem to work here, also i am not sure how to enter the div in the html code correctly.

```css
.btn-was {  
  background-size: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  color:#fff;
  margin-bottom:25px;
  padding:10px;
}

.btn-was {
  background-image: url(../img/button.png);
}
```

```html
<a class="btn-was" href="#" role="button">About</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

url() references in css don't raise success/error events so only way to test if image loaded or not is to actually try loading it using js

```
$(".btn-was").each(function() {
    //extract css `background-image` value of this anchor's css
    var bgimg = $(this).css("background-image").match(/url\(["']?([^()]*)["']?\)/).pop();  
    var image = new Image();                   // dummy img for testing
    $(image).error(function() {                // if img didn't load
        console.log(bgimg + " didn't load ");
    $(".btn-was").css('color','black');          // so assign fallback style
    });
    $(image).attr("src", bgimg);               // check if img loads        
});
```

Comment: thank you!
i loaded your script as external .js but i get an error: 
"TypeError: $(...).css(...).match(...) is null"

Comment: Assuming you didn't forget adding jquery try assigning url directly `var bgimg = "http://www.exampl....../img/button.png` on the second line"

Comment: thanks - adding the url made the script stop throwing the error. but the css does not change when the pics are not loaded.

Comment: Try changing `$(this).css('color','black');` to  `$(".btn-was").css('color','black');`

Comment: Ahh looks like I forgot to see that `this` inside image error function refers to `image` itself rather than `.btn-was` :p